# What is the part after the comma referring to in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, commas

> in case of an offer for sale of a government company or statutory authority or corporation or any special purpose vehicle set up and controlled by any one or more of them, which is engaged in the infrastructure sector...

The part after the comma refers to:

- Government company, statutory authority/corporation, Special purpose vehicle; OR
- Special purpose vehicle only

Comment: Lawyers could (and probably would) argue at length over the precise meaning here. Merely as a guideline, commas are often used to _hint at_ lengthier possible preceding strings.

Comment: The prose is irresolvably ambiguous so the question has to be closed as a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. a government company or 2) statutory authority or 3) corporation or 4) any special purpose vehicle set up and controlled by any one or more of them

Any of 1,2,3,4 which is engaged in the infrastructure sector.